# TypeScript - Union type - Naming convention

Tags: typescript, naming-conventions, union-types

I'm new in TS and I have a some problem to resolve.
I have this interface:

```
interface ILayerSet {
  addLayer(layer: ILayer): void;
  removeLayer(layer: ILayer): void;
  removeLayer(position: number): void;
  removeLayer(func: (layer: ILayer) => boolean): void;
}
```

I've read about Union Types and rewrote. Then I started wonder about name of argument. It can be ILayer, number and func, so how to correct name this argument?

```
interface ILayerSet {
  addLayer(layer: ILayer): void;
  removeLayer(WHATNAME: ILayer | number | ((layer: ILayer) => boolean)): void;
}
```

Or maybe better solution  is something like that?

```
interface ILayerSet {
  addLayer(layer: ILayer): void;
  removeLayer(layer: ILayer): void;
  removeLayerByPosition(position: number): void;
  removeLayerByFunc(func: (layer: ILayer) => boolean): void;
}
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: I feel like this is [too opinion-based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The best name I can come up with for the unified argument is "selector", because in all cases, it is used to select the layer to remove.  But either of the other ways of writing the code (with three overload signatures or three separate methods) seems clearer.